# Java kthSmallestElement using Quicksort Infinite Loop Error

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

So I implemented "find the kth smallest element in an array" using a modified quicksort algorithm. However, right now it is infinite looping. I'm not quite sure where the error is. **Updated: The debugger says the error is on line 14: "return kthSmallestError(arr, start, j-1, k); According to print statements, the (start, j-1, k) values are (3, 3, 0)"** Thanks for the help!

```
class kthSmallestElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7};
        int result = kthSmallestElement(input, 0, input.length-1, 3);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public static int kthSmallestElement(int[] arr, int start, int end, int k) {
        int j = partition(arr, start, end);
        if (j == k) return arr[j];
        if (j < k) {
            return kthSmallestElement(arr, j+1, end, k-j-1);
        }
        else {
            return kthSmallestElement(arr, start, j-1, k);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int pivot = arr[left+(right-left)/2];

        while (left <= right) {
            while (arr[left] < pivot) {
                left++;
            }
            while (arr[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if (left <= right) {
                int temp = arr[left];
                arr[left] = arr[right];
                arr[right] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
}
```

Comment: So use a debugger to see the condition that makes your loop becoming infinite, then ask yourself what's making the condition to arise and how to solve it.

Comment: After seeing (3, 3, 0), you can start using your brain to run the code step by step. You should be able to see why it will not stop.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious bug: `left, right, j` are absolute indices whie `k` is relative. All comparisons and arithmetics between `j` and `k` should be calibrated by `start`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

thanks,

--john

```
    public static int kthSmallestElement(int[] arr, int start, int end, int k) {
    //int j = partition(arr, start, end);
    int j = partition2(arr, start, end);
    if (j == k)
        return arr[j];
    if (j < k) {
        // without -1 as original code.
        return kthSmallestElement(arr, j + 1, end, k - j );
    } else {
        return kthSmallestElement(arr, start, j - 1, k);
    }
}

public static int partition2(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    int left = lo;
    int right = hi+1;
    int p = arr[lo];

    while (true) {
        while (arr[++left] < p) {
            if (left == hi)
                break;
        }

        while (p < arr[--right]) {
            if (right == lo) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (left >= right) {
            break;
        }

        exchange(arr, left, right);
    }

    exchange(arr, lo, right);
    return right;
}
```